# What is the connection between product attribute sets and categories?

Tags: magento2

**What is the connection between product attribute sets and categories?**

1. Categories have no connection to product attribute sets, and any product can be assigned to any category
2. Each category is linked to a single product attribute set, and only products from that attribute set are allowed in the category
3. Each category is linked to a single product attribute set, and only products from that category’s set or any of its parent categories’
4. Categories can be connected to multiple product attribute sets, and only products from one of those sets are allowed in the category

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Categories have no connection to product attribute sets, and any product can be assigned to any category**

This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Categories have no connection to product attribute sets, and any product can be assigned to any category.

it seems to be the right one.